# How to add horizontal lines for different facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, geom-hline

I want to add horizontal line to a facetted barplot using `ggplot2`.

I have two nutrient types, each with a different guideline value I would like to display and I want the plots to appear side by side in a single frame.

Data looks like this:

```
Trip   Depth       NutrientType   ugL
  <fct>  <fct>       <chr>        <int>
1 Before Surface     TN            1111
2 Before Surface     TP             162
3 Before Near bottom TN            1428
4 Before Near bottom TP             191
5 After  Surface     TN             869
6 After  Surface     TP             756
7 After  Near bottom TN             816
8 After  Near bottom TP             487
```

Current code:

```
BARR1plot <- ggplot(
  BARR1,
  aes(
    x = Depth,
    y = ugL,
    fill = Trip
  )
) +
  geom_bar(colour = "black", stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 18)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  ylab("Concentration (µg/L)") +
  xlab("") +
  facet_grid(~NutrientType, scales = "fixed", switch = "x") +
  labs(title = "BARR1") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0)) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "mm"))
```

I have searched through previous questions and added code to my existing plot code using `geom_hline` but both lines appear across both plots rather than just with their associated nutrient type.

Currently using this code:

```
data_hline <- data.frame(
  group = unique(BARR1$NutrientType),
  hline = c(900, 250)
)

BARR1plot +
  geom_hline(
    data = data_hline,
    aes(yintercept = hline)
  )
```

But get this result:

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you facet by `NutrientType` but in the data for the `geom_hline` you named the column containing the nutrient type  `group`. Hence, this data will not be facetted and both lines will be displayed in both facet panels.

To fix that rename your column.

```
library(ggplot2)

data_hline <- data.frame(
  NutrientType = unique(BARR1$NutrientType),
  hline = c(900, 250)
)

BARR1plot +
  geom_hline(
    data = data_hline,
    aes(yintercept = hline)
  )
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
BARR1 <- structure(list(Trip = c(
  "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before",
  "After", "After", "After", "After"
), Depth = c(
  "Surface", "Surface",
  "Near bottom", "Near bottom", "Surface", "Surface", "Near bottom",
  "Near bottom"
), NutrientType = c(
  "TN", "TP", "TN", "TP", "TN",
  "TP", "TN", "TP"
), ugL = c(
  1111L, 162L, 1428L, 191L, 869L, 756L,
  816L, 487L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1", "2", "3",
  "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"
))
```